# Poor model fit for confirmatory factor analysis

Tags: confirmatory-factor

I am currently doing a confirmatory factor analysis using AMOS. I have 229 cases, no missing data, with a standardized questionnaire of 20 items, 4 factors. However, some indices specify that it does not fit well: chi-square= 343.322, df=64; GFI=.874; CFI=.817; RMSEA= 0.69.

What should I do? Maybe add the number of my respondents? try out another model?

Answer (score 1):

That's a horribly fitting model (if you don't mind my saying).

What you do next depends on where that model came from. The model is wrong - if there's a theory that says that that model should fit the data, the theory is wrong. Maybe you can stop there.

If I wanted to make something of this scale, I would go to exploratory factor analysis.